# Why doesn't FB Like button show correct like count?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When I click my Like button, it does add the activity to my FB (per screenshot) but the count stays at zero (also per screenshot), why?

I've checked the Linter tool and everything looks to be fine.

The site is [www.FindCuro.com](http://www.FindCuro.com)

[image]

Here is my code (MVC)

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookAppId"]&amp;xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.findcuro.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: It's better for you and community to ask "bonus" question as a separate question! ;)

Comment: Please give us your current code.

Comment: Is your application is sandboxed? Does user viewing this activity have access to application? Any chances "Piter" is a test user?

Comment: Will do.  I thought about doing that originally but then I feel like I would be asking too many questions :)

Comment: Sandbox mode is disabled.  Peter is an Administrator.  I've viewed the page from other browsers when I'm not logged in and even on other PCs but they all show 0 likes.  I will post code.

Comment: @FeatureCreep, is number of likes is correct while Piter is looking on the like button?

Comment: @Juicy Scripter, No, the only time I've ever seen it at "1" is when I (Piter/Peter) "liked" it.  Once I refreshed the page, it went back to zero.

Comment: @JuicyScripter, Note that Peter is the Administrator, in case the matters.

Comment: @Martn & JuicyScripter Thanks guys.  It was a case problem.  Why doesn't FB call that out in the Linter, or like button docs, or in the OpenGraph metta tag documentation?  I read all that thinking I was doing my due diligence.  Once I knew what I was looking for, I see that FB does have documentation talking about it but not nearly as prominent as it should be.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the like button.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.FindCuro.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

You shouldn't be using "FindCuro.com" (note the capital letters)

If you check https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.FindCuro.com/ you'll see two shares
If you check https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.findcuro.com/ you won't see any shares

Facebook is checking the second one.

try all lowercases.

Comment: & JuicyScripter Thanks guys. It was a case problem. Why doesn't FB call that out in the Linter, or like button docs, or in the OpenGraph metta tag documentation? I read all that thinking I was doing my due diligence. Once I knew what I was looking for, I see that FB does have documentation talking about it but not nearly as prominent as it should be. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the fact that page located on URL you using for like button have **Canonical URL** that cannot be resolved due to cyclical redirects: `http://www.FindCuro.com/` (See [output of Debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.findcuro.com/) for initial URL and [the one for Canonical URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.FindCuro.com/))

Provide lowercase **Canonical URL** in the OpenGraph meta tags should solve the issue.

BTW, If you'll use `standard` layout for Like Button you will probably see error message while liking with user who is admin of application. Also activity story about liking page is sent regardless of real like number increase.